# What is someone who often addresses bad things about someone?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word to describe someone who focuses on the bad parts of someone else and talks about it often.

Example: He's (insert word); He likes talking about every single mistake I make.

Comment: Does this help? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172886/a-word-for-the-urge-to-point-out-others-minor-mistakes-not-to-define-this-ph

Answer (score 0):

> He's  **hypercritical**; he likes talking about every single mistake I
> make.

**hypercritical** (adj.)

> *Hypercritical* means *over, unduly, unnecessarily critical*. [R. P. Utter; *Every-day Words and Their Uses*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Every_day_Words_and_Their_Uses/BElZAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=hypercritical%20every%20mistake&pg=PA139&printsec=frontcover) (1916)

> Meticulously or excessively critical [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypercritical)

> Excessively and unreasonably critical, especially of small faults.
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hypercritical)
>
> *He was a sarcastic, hypercritical man*

> Too critical; too severe in judgment; hard to please [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hypercritical)

---

> The mistakes we make on stage are important. ...
> So, after your
> present, write down what you wish you could have done differently...
> A word of caution: This isn't a call to be **hypercritical** — no, no
> no. Instead, it's an opportunity to ... [J. Borensztajn; *21 Steps to Become an Awesome Public Speaker*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/21_Steps_to_Become_an_Awesome_Public_Spe/ph64DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=hypercritical%20every%20mistake&pg=PT38&printsec=frontcover)

> John's history revealed what might be happening. He had spent a dozen
> years in a relationship with one woman who was **hypercritical**. In
> addition, he noted that his mother was also **hypercritical**, cold,
> and rejecting. A close examination of his pattern of relating to both
> these women showed that when John felt ignored or did not receive
> adequate attention or affection, he felt unloved and rejected. [S.
> Methven et al.; *If Only I Had Known*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/If_Only_I_Had_Known_Avoiding_Common_Mist/QKaRM7GYU5QC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=hypercritical%20every%20mistake&pg=PA157&printsec=frontcover)